# Error al enviar correo con PHP Mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tengo un formulario el cuál mando por correo utilizando PHP Mailer, funcionaba perfectamente cuando lo puse en un sitio a finales del año pasado, pero hoy el cliente me informa que cada que intenta enviar el formulario aparece el mensaje de error que yo definí para hacer la comprobación de envío, y no se cuál pueda ser el problema, implemente el mismo formulario para varias páginas del sitio y en todas pasa lo mismo.

```
<?php
$nombre = $empresa = $correo = $asunto = $mensaje = $captcha = $para = NULL;
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$empresa = $_POST["empresa"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$asunto = $_POST["asunto"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];
$captcha = $_POST["captcha"];
$para = 'jcarlos_cst@outlook.com';

$keySecret = "6LfFFi4UAAAAAOhZGnLHXftPBG4dHL-sq8_DfR3Y";
$verificacion = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$keySecret}&response={$captcha}");
$respGoogle = json_decode($verificacion);

if($respGoogle->success == true){
    //echo "OK. Google validó el captcha :)";
    //Reseteamos variables a 0.

      //Componemos nuestro correo electronico

      //Incluimos libreria PHPmailer (deberas descargarlo).
      require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';


      //Nuevo correo electronico.
      $mail = new PHPMailer();
      //Caracteres.
      $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

      //De dirección correo electrónico y el nombre
      $mail->From = $correo;
      $mail->FromName = $nombre;

      //Dirección de envio y nombre.
      $mail->addAddress($para, "IMECPLAST");
      //Dirección a la que responderá destinatario.
      $mail->addReplyTo($correo,$nombre);

      //BCC ->  incluir copia oculta de email enviado.
      $mail->addBCC("jcarlos_cst@outlook.com");

      //Enviar codigo HTML o texto plano.
      $mail->isHTML(true);

      //Titulo email.
      $mail->Subject = $asunto;
      //Cuerpo email con HTML.
      $mail->Body = "
              <h1>Correo de Prueba</h1>

              Nombre: $nombre<br />
                      Empresa: $empresa<br />
              Email: $correo <br />
              Mensaje: $mensaje <br />

      "; 
    //Comprobamos el envio.
    if(!$mail->send()) {                   
        echo "Mensaje no Enviado vuelva a intentar";
    } else {
        echo "<b>Hemos recibido tu mensaje, te contestaremos lo más pronto posible</b>";
    } 
}
else if($respGoogle->success == false){
    echo "Error. Google no validó el captcha :(";
}
?>
```

Ese es el código que utilice, y dado que llega hasta el mensaje "Mensaje no Enviado vuelva a intentar" descarto que sea un error del captcha. ¿Alguna idea de cual podría ser el problema?

[En este el link esta el formulario por si sirve de algo.](http://www.imecplast.com.mx/contacto.html)

Comment: Aqui tienes un ejemplo sencillo: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example

Comment: yo no veo donde defines el servidor de correos, deberias definirlo como lo hace en el ejemplo, es decir el host, user y pass

Comment: Cuando lo ponía como en el ejemplo me mandaba un error con vendor, pero lo volveré a intentar.

Comment: Convendría que muestres el error, el cual te podría orientar sobre el problema que puede estar ocurriendo: `echo "Mensaje no Enviado vuelva a intentar. El error es: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;`

Comment: Could not instantiate mail function. 

Ese es el error que manda. No entiendo por que antes si funcionaba y ahora no.